# Understanding TS error when assigning value to an object dynamic property (which key is from a Union Type)

Tags: typescript, object

I'm trying to understand why TS is warning that `Type 'someValueHere' is not assignable to type 'undefined'` when assigning a value to a dynamic property which key is one of a Union type of strings

here is the link to the playground: [Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJxASRDA9gZ2QG8BYAKGWQgFs5gAbAfgC5l8wpQBzAbnMoBGwKGAAWAEziQWbDtz4VkAB1G4QEEAFdqA6DPacQvfshjD2IONQj65RhZXpwLVm6wPyTuJWFAB9BFxqJQhfXzUZAVxceggMB2RvXxA-fE0BfAROH2AI1iiYuJAFAF9ycjAATxC0YAh6cWQAXmITS2tWAGsIStwYNAxsPHxyMrJyQJB2RJyUtIys4By1PzN68VZUOobm1sV2iFYAIiT-eczs8JAj0fKySenuyr8QXDA-OHp6XAB3CHFVrgoC9XH5-GsGptto0WqR9q5jvgghA-E8bmQxncIAAPJRAsDIB4E2jddBYHAEbDAXyfADKYCkEFQUCCqCB1C260ILQAFCYIeJ8FD1gBtAC6ABpyABKTaDCncgB8pmh+AAdFB-pokDyebgBAArCUq9bS5rKuGUfUGkUCtUHMW7ADkSOsVFoDCdCWtIqdQhEEkZTsdLRdyOQ-rEkkgXpMmrAmigIEShtKxqIJWQzgG5OG0p4QA)

I'm aware that I'm quite bad at explaining the issue and probably a missing some key concepts here ...

the question can probably better phrased too

thanks for any help on this

#### Edit

after looking at problem the again with the help of the accepted answer & comments I can see that the error TS is reporting is due to the fact that the object that is being built in the reduce loop is asserted as being of type FanInfos and that the assignments in the loop are not matching all the possible types of the FanInfos interface properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```js
interface FanInfos {
  email?: string;
  birthdate?: string;
  phonenumber?: string;
  firstname?: string;
  lastname?: string;
  optin_competition?: boolean;
  optin_subscription?: boolean;
}
```

Is not a Union type of optional strings, but contains some optional boolean values.

If `field.name` was "optin_competition" or "optin_subscription", you would assign a string to an optional boolean

Comment: thanks, what I don't understand is that I was after getting the keys of FanInfos as possible values for _field.name_ and it seemed like _keyof FanInfos_ would achieve just that. But obviously there is something I don't get ... I edited the playground to show that if I try and use one the boolean typed property on FanInfos as a_field.name_ it compiles but not if I use _field.name_ as the key of a property on the object I'm trying to build

Comment: keyof FanInfos works as you expect, [see here](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJxASRDA9gZ2QG8BYAKGWQgFs5gAbAfgC5l8wpQBzAbnMoBGwKGAAWAEziQWbDtz4VkAB1G4QEEAFdqA6DPacQvfshjD2IONQj65RhZXpwLVm6wPyTuJWFAB9BFxqJQhfXzVbQ2NFb18QP3xNAXwETh9gCPc7aIBfcnIwAE8QtGAIenFkAF5iE0trVgBrCELcGDQMbDx8cjyyckCQdmRY-0Tk1OB0tT8zcvFWVDKK6trFeohWACJR+PGUtPCQLd78sggADyVcEWRB4dpm9CwcAmxgXzh6AGUwKQhUFAgqgbtQlvNCDUABQmOYVfCLZbiADaAF0ADTkACUi06r0hAD5TEj8AA6KAQcSaJBQqG4AQAK3RxPmWOqRNIMUZyLh4lJG1RqwA5PggigaHR6EKHCNuUKhCIJP8hYKaiKxcgFWJJJBpSYKWBNFAQLKGQocsyiDlkM4Oi9ulieEA)

Comment: The problem is that in your case `obj[field.name]` could be a `boolean?`, and you can't assign `'some email'` (which is a string) to a `boolean?` field

Comment: thanks, I was not looking at the pb correctly indeed - I now understand that it came from the fact that I'm saying that the object I'm building should be of type FanInfos and has optional boolean possible values for some keys